# Displaying current output in wx.textctrl wigdet from python code entered in another wx.textctrl

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, exec

I use two wx.TextCtrl widgets in my wxApp.
The first one is used to provide Python code by app user, e.g.:

```
from time import sleep  
for i in range(4):  
    print i  
    sleep(4)
```

The second one is used to display the output.
To process user code I use EXEC.
But I have problems with displaying output dynamically.

Currently the output is displayed in second wx.TextCtrl widget but after whole code is processed (after 16 seconds).

I would like to display the user's code output every 4 seconds in above code.
How to do that?

I was trying to use threads but there are problems with using exec in case of threads.

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep will block the GUI's main loop, which is why you don't see any output. You will have to put that into a separate thread if you want to go that route. Otherwise, you could use a wx.Timer.

Here's a tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/

I don't think you should use Python's exec command though. That can lead to code injection issues. Instead, you should consider using the subprocess module.